# How to prove the validity of this argument?

Tags: logic

I have an assignment where I have to prove the validity of a statement, but I am not sure about what I am doing.

This is the assignment:

> Is the statement $(A \wedge B \wedge C) \to D$ a valid argument?
>   Justify your answer with a mathematical proof. Hint 1: a statement is
>   valid if and only if its negation is a contraddiction. Hint 2: try to
>   simplify the body of the implication (i.e., the part $A \wedge B
> \wedge C$) before simplifying the entire formula. Hint 3: a quantified
>   formula is a contraddiction if and only if it is not possible to find
>   a universe satisfying it.

I have done it like this:

I know that

> $A \land B \land C \rightarrow D$

is equivalent to

> $\neg(A \land B \land C) \lor D $

which is equivalent to

> $\neg(A \land B \land C \land \neg D)$

Now if I replace $A \land B \land C$ with P with obtain:

> $\neg (P \land \neg D)$

Know I state that:

> $\forall x (x \in (A \land B \land C \rightarrow D))$

Then I negate it and see if it's a contradiction of the expression above:

> $\neg(\forall x (x \in (A \land B \land C \rightarrow D)))$

Is the same thing as saying exists at least 1 that does not respect the statement:

> $\exists x \neg(x \in (A \land B \land C \rightarrow D))$

And I replace $A \land B \land C$ with P with obtain:

> $\exists x \neg(x \in (P \rightarrow D))$
>
> $\exists x \neg(x \in (\neg P \lor D))$
>
> $\exists x \neg(x \in \neg (P \land \neg D))$

Which is a contradiction of the above statement, right?

Comment: There are $16$ possible options, out of which, this statement is true in $15$ of them and false in the remaining one. In other words, it depends on the values of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$, which you have not specified (making it impossible to give a definite answer of *true* or *false*).

Comment: Read my updated comment above. It is impossible to determine whether or not it is correct, without specifying the values of $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: Just give a counterexample for this statement being always true (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

The statement $A \wedge B \wedge C \rightarrow D$ is not necessarily true:

$[A=true]\wedge[B=true]\wedge[C=true]\wedge[D=false]$

Answer (score 0):

> Is the statement $(A∧B∧C)→D$ a valid argument?

The statement is just one statement.  It is not an argument.

An argument is a series of statements (called premises) intended to prove the truth of another statement (called the conclusion), through some accepted form of logical reasoning.